Wide Shallow Neural Networks VS Deep NN
I have several key points of understanding, but I cannot reach a final conclusion on why shallow neural networks cannot model data as effectively as deep neural networks.

I understand that we can represent any complicated function in a lower-dimensional space using a simpler function in a higher-dimensional space.

I understand that machine learning models in higher-dimensional spaces are more susceptible to overfitting, as a high-dimensional lookup table can memorize the data.

I understand that deeper neural networks can model nonlinearities better than shallow neural networks, thus providing a better estimate of the true function mapping the input to the output.

I understand that kernel methods project data to an infinite-dimensional space and calculate the dot product between pairs. In an infinite-dimensional space, any two datasets can be linearly separated, and the dot product can help determine to which dataset a testing point belongs. The projection to a higher-dimensional space is not explicitly learned.


Given these observations, why do shallow neural networks fail? Projecting a data point to a much higher-dimensional space seems beneficial, but it is prone to overfitting. This issue also affects deep neural networks. So, what am I missing here?
